# I need to record a demo of our application. Can anyone recommend a good screen recorder?

Tags: screen-capture

I need to record a demo of our application. Can anyone recommend a good screen recorder?

I have tried CamStudio, but it's throwing errors. Any other good free software I should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try UVScreenCamera, i think it's normal

Comment: Thanks Mishgun. Out of all the utilities I tried UVScreencamera worked the best.

Answer (score 2):

Camtasia studio does a great job.
In the case the app is cross-platform (java, web-based) you can ask a pal with a Mac to use Screenium, Snapz Pro or ScreenFlow.

Answer (score 1):

Static screen shots?  Maybe Wink will work for you as well:

[Problem‍​​ Steps Recorder tool to make tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876889/steps-recorder-tool-to-make-tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [ScreenToaster](http://www.screentoaster.com/) without installing any software (kind of).

Otherwise if you prefer a traditional application [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/) and [Screen2EXE](http://www.screen-record.com/screen2exe.htm) are both free.

Comment: screentoaster is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) is freeware. From their homepage:

> Wink is a Tutorial and Presentation creation software, primarily aimed at creating tutorials on how to use software (like a tutor for MS-Word/Excel etc). Using Wink you can capture screenshots, add explanations boxes, buttons, titles etc and generate a highly effective tutorial for your users.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of screen recording tools around, both free and professional ones, but I haven’t seen anything like ScreenToaster before. It's very nice applications for screen recording.