# How to record Flash player output

Tags: flash, framebuffer

Is there any way to record what flash player displays? I thought of sampling the framebuffer contents like 30 times per second but i am not sure if that is even possible under Windows.

**note:** i know that there are plenty of software that converts swf to avi, but i wanna do it programmatically because my aim is not to save them to my disk as avi or sth.

Comment: but if you don't want to save result on your disc, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: play with it in many other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can get BitmapData of any DisplayObject, I suppose if you have some parent class, inherited from Sprite or MovieClip, where you display everything, you can get BitmapData of this parent object, and this will be a "screenshot" of your flash movie. I usually use next function to get BitmapData;

```
function getBitmapData( target:DisplayObject ) : BitmapData{
    var bd : BitmapData = new BitmapData( target.width, target.height,true, 0x0 );
    bd.draw( target );
    return bd;
}
```

So you can create a "screenshots" of your swf, and save them in some array of Bitmaps or any other way you like.

Comment: cool, but i do not have access to AS in any way. I have swf file already compiled (created or whatever) and that will be displayed on flash player. what i want to do is to somehow intercept and grab the final image(s) before being put on screen.

Comment: So you want to get screens from the swf which even not yet shown. No you cannot do this from outside of the flash. This should violate all possible security rules.

Comment: well, let's say like this: i have swf, i want to play it 'virtually' and capture the output programmatically

Comment: do you want to do this once on your local machine, or you want to do this every time user communicate with your app?

Comment: i want to do this once on my local machine

Comment: so you can use some app for creating win macros (like http://www.flashplayerpro.com/MacroRecorder/) with some screen graber (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876887/i-need-to-record-a-demo-of-our-application-can-anyone-recommend-a-good-screen-re)